# How to mock Dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush() using powermock and mokito

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, powermock

I have a function which is taking request and sending the response and creating Junit test case for the method but i am unable to mock Dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();

My test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SessionFactory.class,Session.class})

public class ClassNameTest{
     private ClassName className;
     private ServiceDao mockServiceDao = mock(ServiceDaoImpl.class);

     @Test 
     public void testAbc() { 
          SessionFactory mockSessionFactory=PowerMockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);
          Session mockedSession= PowerMockito.mock(Session.class);
          mockServiceDao.setSessionFactory(mockSessionFactory);
          Mockito.when(mockSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);

          ---rest of the code---
     }
```

while debuging it's throwing exception at mDao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

note: my jars r correct as I tried demo example with final and static classes and the test was successful but for this project its creating mock object for Sessionfactory but not for session.

Comment: why aren't you able to mock it?

Comment: bcoz getCurrentSession() is a final method.

Comment: That is not a problem Powermock can mock final methods just fine

Comment: SessionFactory is mocking but session is not mocking by the above code

Comment: can you make that part of the question? It is next to impossible to read in the comments

Comment: on debug Dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush(); is showing exception.

Comment: What exception? Add it to your question!

Comment: Also learn how to ask questions: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: The way I mocked SessionFactory and Session ok?

Comment: If it throws an exception ... probably not.

Comment: Oh dear, the exception gets thrown at a line that isn't even in the  source code you show us. How are we supposed to help? I'm leaving this thread now and voting to close.

Comment: Dear sir, I think the q I posted u didn't understand properly but no probs......next tm I will frame it more accurately.....thnx for all those lovely advices.

Answer (score 0):

In short, don't do this.  You are creating a very brittle test that doesn't actually prove what you want it to.  You're mocking how to use a framework which gives you no guarantees on if your code actually works at all.

For these kinds of tests you actually want to round-trip to an actual database and forget mocking altogether.  You can do as much mocking here as possible and your code can *still not actually work*.

Comment: But my test method contains the business logic and some validation of the request object which is why i am testing the method but the only thing that is creating problem is   Dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush(); which is 1st-level cache and its job is to clear old value.And commenting the line(Dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();) my test case is running successfully.So plz suggest how to mock it.